# Websocket, iPad, Chrome and Safari, onend kills browser

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-chrome, safari, websocket

I've a HTML app that uses websockets. All is good on both desktop as well as iPad (Safari and Chrome latest versions), except from one thing. If *I have an open connection* and kills the server, both browsers **on the iPad only**, just **blows up** and shuts down. It works on the desktop.

Is there a way to access some log files or anything? Tried to wrap the code where I handle `onclose` in a `try-catch` but had no success.

The workflow is like this: `ws.onclose` start an interval that tries to reconnect. It's as simple as that.

Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "blow up"? I saw how iPad's Safari just exits on overload (not sure - CPU or other resources). Is this yours "blow up"? Also it's not clear if the code with reconnecting on `onclose` is used normally (so it can be the reason of the "blow up" as itself), or just added after the problem has been discovered?

Comment: Does disabling the reconnect code still result in the browser "blowing up"?

Comment: Blowing up as in immediate shutdown. It's a simple interval 2s that ONLY if the ws is closed tries to create a new one. Will remove all that and see if it's the END message from the server causing it.

Comment: Please, don't forget to mention @usernames in replies. What is the server and how do you kill it? Can you make a simple client test and run it with another websocket server (to be killed)?

Comment: @Daniel did you solve your problem? I do have an similiar situation just without the interval in the onclose event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438712/reasons-for-safari-to-crash